# Receive parameters in Rest controller from Post method using Spring and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send two parameters using AJAX to my Spring REST controller using the POST method. However those parameters are appearing as `null` in my controller. Please find the code and let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
var formData = {
  txToClose: '1234,5678,98549',
  sno:  '0195'
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: url,
  async: false,  
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",      
  success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    console.log(result);
  }                           
});
```

```java
@PostMapping("/txToClose")  
public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws BBException
{
  logger.info("Called txToClose controller");
  ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();

  String txToClose = request.getParameter("txToClose");
  String sno = request.getParameter("sno");

  logger.info("Transactions to close :" + txToClose + ", Serial Num :" + sno);
}
```

Comment: Aside from the issue, you should really remove `async: false`. It's horrendous practice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, any idea on why those parameters are not received?

Comment: No sorry. I have no experience with Spring.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, No problem. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Is the control coming under the controller??? See from ur logs

Comment: @Mohit, its coming, Im printing those values right? It means the control is available in controller

Comment: try printing the request uri using the getRequestURI() function'

Comment: also try giving the full url in the url parameter in the ajax call to e.g. localhost:8080/txToClose

Comment: Its pointing to controller Mohit.

Comment: Its printing /BB/txToClose for Request URI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156535/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-mohit).

Answer (score 0):

create class like this :

```
    class Myclass{
          private String  txToClose;
             private String    sno; 
 // getters setters
    }
```

and in your method like this :

```
@PostMapping("/txToClose")  
public ResultDto txToClose(@RequestBody Myclass class ) throws BBException
{
   // your logic
}
```

Comment: but other than creating class, why cannot I receive by using request.getparameter ?

Comment: I tried in your way, but still its not working. @Requestbody has 415 unsupported media type, so I used ModelAttribute, but still null values are passing

Comment: sincerely i never used request.getParameter() to get param json in spring ,but you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781980/read-json-in-java-servlet/34782168

Comment: adding content type  to your request application/json

Comment: public boolean txToClose(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) { } This worked

Answer (score 0):

I think the part which is not working in your code is the request.getParameter() as it would not be able to identify the paramters and values in case of json data.
Instead use something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
try {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line).append('\n');
      }
 } 
 finally {
        reader.close();
 }
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Use the above logic in your controller to process the json request.Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548782/retrieving-json-object-literal-from-httpservletrequest) for further ideas to process json when taken as HttpServeletRequest.

Comment: Mohit.. I solved the issue. public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody ObjectNode json) throws BBException
{
    logger.info("Called txToClosecontroller");
    ResultDto result = new ResultDto();

    String txToClose= json.get("txToClose").asText();
}

Comment: You used an entity to take the request then right??

Comment: It could have been possible without the @RequestBody as well, do try my method once to see whether it works or not. Just for testing purpose, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody ObjectNode json) throws BBException { 
    logger.info("Called txToClosecontroller"); 
    ResultDto result = new ResultDto(); 
    String txToClose= json.get("txToClose").asText(); 
}
```